# breaking down string based on characters

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop

I have got a string which consists of a list of x and y coordinates. The x and y coordinates are separated by a comma, and each coordinate ends with a dot indicating the end of the coordinate. I need to break this string down to get each x and y coordinate but I cannot get my for loop to work properly

For example:

```
String coords= "3,1.2,0.1,1.0,2.1,3.2,3.3,3.";
```

each comma separates x and y coordinate. The dot(.) ends the coordinate and starts a new one. So the actual coordinate list would look like this.

> - X:3, Y:1
> - X:2, Y:0
> - X:1, Y:1
> - X:0, Y:2
> - ....  ....
> - ....  ....

The reason it is done in a weird way like this is because I'm working on a robotics project and there is a memory issue, so I can't use arrays for the coords, therefore a single string has to be passed to the embedded system from PC which needs to be broken down into coords.

Comment: You could See my single line solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
    String coords= "3,1.2,0.1,1.0,2.1,3.2,3.3,3.";
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < coords.length(); i = j + 1) {
        j = coords.indexOf(".", i);
        if (j == -1) break;
        int k = coords.indexOf(",", i);
        int x = Integer.parseInt(coords.substring(i, k));
        int y = Integer.parseInt(coords.substring(k + 1, j));
        System.out.printf("X:%d, Y:%d%n", x, y);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
String coords= "3,1.2,0.1,1.0,2.1,3.2,3.3,3.";
for(int i=0; i< coords.length(); i++)
{
    if ( coords.charAt(i) == '.' )
    {
        String s = coords.substring(i);

        System.out.println("X:"+ s.split(",")[0] + " " + "Y:"+s.split(",")[1] );
    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. I can't use array, this is for a robotics project and there is a constraint with memory. I don't even get any output for some reason.

Comment: what is your exact requirement ? to get all X, Y s in a single string?

Comment: Yes, the coords are passed as a single string. I need to process and break each string down (read each coord )and work with it. Even if I can get an output of it, I'll be able to manage it from there.

Comment: The approach is correct but when I use a coordinate with more than one characters, e.g. 30,15,21 or 120. It is unable to separate it. Works okay for one char digits.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to get output string then one approach would be just using string `replace()` method,

**NO** `for`loop, **NO** `split()` and **NO** `array` like this:

```
String s = "3,12.23,0.1,1.0,2.1,3.2,3.3,3";
s = "X:"+s.replace(",", ",Y:").replace(".", "\nX:");        
System.out.println(s)
```

Output:

```
X:3,Y:1
X:2,Y:0
X:1,Y:1
X:0,Y:2
X:1,Y:3
X:2,Y:3
X:3,Y:3
```

Answer (score 0):

One fairly easy way to do this is to use a regular expression.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+),(\\d+)\\.");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
while (matcher.find()) {
    int x = Integer.parse(matcher.group(1));
    int y = Integer.parse(matcher.group(2));
    // do whatever you need to do to x and y
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the split method (first time to split between dots, second time to split between commas)

```
public class SplitCoordinates {
    static public void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "3,1.2,0.1,1.0,2.1,3.2,3.3,3";
        for (String s2: s.split("\\.")) {
            String[] s3 = s2.split("\\,");
            int x = Integer.parseInt(s3[0]);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(s3[1]);
            System.out.println( "X:" + x + ",Y:" + y );
        }
    }
}
```